# Extract raw data from Mathematica, so that I can replot in Excel

Tags: plotting, export

How can I extract a raw data from Mathematica? So I can re-plot on Excel. I already tried some command like `Cases` and `ListPlot`, but I don't get the results that I want.

I want to plot the following:

```
4738 x^2 + y (1000 + 1309 y) + x (1000 + 3333 y) = 4398
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) Please take the introductory [Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: As for your question, I think `Export` will be your friend here.

Comment: Have you considered exporting a high-res image of your plot that could then be imported into Excel and other MS Office products? `"PNG"` is a good format for this. With `p = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]`, then `SetDirectory[$UserDocumentsDirectory]; Export["plot.png", Magnify[p, 2], "PNG"]; ResetDirectory[];` should do the the trick.

Answer (score 5):

```
sol = Solve[4738 x^2 + y (1000 + 1309 y) + x (1000 + 3333 y) == 4398, 
  y]

Plot[y /. sol, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

```
Table[{x, y /. sol[[1]]}, {x, -1.2, 1.2, .1}] // TableForm
```

and

```
Table[{x, y /. sol[[2]]}, {x, -1.2, 1.2, .1}] // TableForm
```

get the raw data for *Excel*.

Answer (score 3):

```
ContourPlot[
  4738 x^2 + y (1000 + 1309 y) + x (1000 + 3333 y) == 4398, {x, -1.5, 
   1.5}, {y, -3.2, 2.2}][[1, 1]]
```